# Automatic API doc for Typescript & Node (koa)

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, koa, api-doc

I am using Typescript with Koa. Can someone tell me how can I generate automatic API documentation (not manually)?  I saw there is a package **tsoa** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsoa) but I only want to have a simple API doc for my **routes**, so I don't want to create controllers.

Comment: If you need answer still you can look at packages like koa-docs koa-joi-swagger and koa-oai-router

Comment: Than you, @SaveliTomac! I finally used https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-swagger-decorator